# Matlab/Excel: Write the eta greek letter η in an Excel File using Matlab

Tags: matlab, vba

This is what I've tried so far. In MATLAB:

```
A = ['ß' 'η'];
xlswrite(test.xlsx,A);
```

The beta symbol `ß` is well printed, however a `?` is printed instead of the eta `η`.
I tried to record a macro in Excel to see the VBA script when I inserted both symbol, this is whtat I found:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ß"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "?"
Range("B2").Select
```

I'm feeling stuck and I'm not familiar with VBA.

Comment: Matlab does not do unicode at all.

Comment: @ja72: What do you mean by "do"?  Matlab `char` fundamental type holds Unicode characters, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html

Comment: @ja72 This is not correct : Matlab does not handle unicode by default, but it can completely handle utf-8 for instance with proper settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `char`

```
A = [char(946), char(951)];
xlswrite('test.xlsx', A);
```